# How would you calculate $\cos\left(2\arcsin\frac{4}{5}\right)$ without calculator

Tags: trigonometry

Without the 2, the answer is easily 3/5. But with 2, how do you visualize the new triangle in order to get the result?

Comment: Hint: Think http://www.l7comix.com/ipt/20051125_inspire.png

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$\cos2\phi=1-2\sin^2\phi$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** $\cos 2x=2\cos^2x-1=1-2\sin^2 x$. Now substitute $x=\arcsin\frac 45$ into either reduction. (@drhab wrote the sine version before I did.)